# Physics breakthroughs in the last two decades

Tags: soft-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important discoveries/breakthroughs in physics recently?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4669/what-are-the-most-important-discoveries-breakthroughs-in-physics-recently)

The last two decades have seen significant advances in mathematics, where long standing conjectures have been proved, leading to much further research.
Two great examples would be Wiles' proof of the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture (and hence, Fermat's Last Theorem) and Perelman's proof of the Poincare and Thurston conjectures.

Have there been any comparable advances in theoretical physics in the last 20 years ?

I know there have been very important experimental discoveries such as the accelerating universe and neutrino oscillations.

But I am asking specifically about theoretical discoveries in the last 20 years where, say, some long unexplained phenomenon has been understood and predictions have matched quantitatively with experiment to high accuracy.

Comment: I read the answers to the "possible duplicate" question. Those mainly refer to either experimental breakthroughs or progress in string theory which has not connected with experiment as yet.

Comment: Well, any answers that would be appropriate here would also be appropriate at the duplicate question.

Comment: But not necessarily the other way round. ;-) In any case, if nobody's interested in answering here, I'll just keep checking for more answers to the earlier question.